# Record all Audio to a File

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, audio

Is it possible to intercept all audio data sent to a speaker and write it to a file? I am trying to extract the audio content of a video but I do not have a microphone.

Comment: Can't help you without knowing what OS, at the very least.

Comment: Windows (either 7 or 8 would work)

Comment: All audio or something specific?

Comment: All audio the computer sends to the speaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With either a file or a streaming address, you can use ffmpeg to extract the audio.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input -map 0:a:0 -c copy output.mkv
```

I've used a Matroska (MKV) file because it can handle pretty much any audio codec - the only major exception I know of is Opus, and that's unlikely to be part of a video file at the moment. If you know which audio codec is in use, you can use a different format. If you just want to extract it as an MP3, you can re-encode:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input -map 0:a:0 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3
```

`input` can be either a file, or a streaming address.

Now, to answer your actual question, again [with ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20grab%20the%20desktop%20%28screen%29%20with%20FFmpeg#Windows). First, use the following command to list your dshow devices:

```
ffmpeg.exe -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

...the last few lines of which should be something like this:

```
[dshow @ 000000000214c940] DirectShow video devices
[dshow @ 000000000214c940]  "HP Truevision HD"
[dshow @ 000000000214c940] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 000000000214c940]  "Internal Mic (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)"
[dshow @ 000000000214c940]  "Stereo Mix (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

In my case, I used (on Windows 8)

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)" output.wav
```

...which captured all the sound from my laptop's audio output. The name of the relevant device will probably be different on your computer. To stop recording, press `q` with the command prompt in focus.

Comment: My list doesn't have a stereo mix or anything like that. Is there a way to add it?
`DirectShow audio devices
 "Microphone (Cirrus Logic CS4206A (AB 09))"
 "Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (Cirrus Logic CS4206A (AB 09))"`

Comment: Well, it's probably not the Microphone, so I'd suggest trying out `-i audio="Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (Cirrus Logic CS4206A (AB 09))"`

Comment: how do I finish the recording?

Comment: With the command prompt in focus, press `q`

Comment: hmm... the audio file was empty which makes me think "Digital Audio" was the wrong device. Is it possible I have speakers not showing up in the -list_devices call?

Comment: I wonder if you could just use ffmpeg with the original video file instead

Comment: its an online flash player so I don't have the original file

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really an expert on directshow devices... the only thing I can think of is if you accidentally left the sound on your computer muted or something (since this should record audio the same as it comes out of your speakers). Maybe try asking on the [ffmpeg-users mailing list](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/ffmpeg-user/) or the [Zeranoe forum](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=7)

Comment: If it's an online flash player, there's a pretty strong possibility that you can just download the file. There are dozens of Firefox extensions that can do it; I use DownloadHelper, which actually has the ability to convert the videos to MP3.

Comment: I have tried everything to extract the video, but ultimately it seems I am going to need to capture the audio/video of the video.